# Do all variables in methods need to be object properties? (PHP)

Tags: php, parameters, this, declaration

I'm learning OO PHP and am trying to get some of the coding practices straight. Here is a pared down version of some code I'm using for error (and exception) handling:

```
final class MyErrorExceptionHandler {

    private $level = array(); // error levels to be handled as standard errors
    private $path = array(); // full path to file
    private $path_short; // filename plus working dir

    public function myErrorHandler($severity, $message, $file, $line) {
        if (error_reporting() & $severity) { // error code is included in error_reporting
            $this->level = array(E_WARNING => 'warning',
                E_NOTICE => 'notice',
                E_USER_WARNING => 'user warning',
                E_USER_NOTICE => 'user notice');
            if (array_key_exists($severity, $this->level)) { // handle as standard error
                /*$this->severity = $severity;
                $this->message = $message;
                $this->file = $file;
                $this->line = $line;*/
                $this->printMessage($severity, $message, $file, $line);
            } else { // fatal: E_USER_ERROR or E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR use php's ErrorException converter
                throw new ErrorException($message, 0, $severity, $file, $line);
            }
        }
    } // fn myErrorHandler

    private function printMessage($severity, $message, $file, $line) {
        echo ucfirst($this->level[$severity]) . ': ' . $message;
        $this->shortenPath($file);
        echo ' in ' . $this->path_short . ' on line ' . $line;
    } // fn printMessage

    private function shortenPath($file) {
        $this->path_short = $file;
        $this->path = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $file);
        if (count($this->path) > 2) { // shorten path to one dir, if more than one dir
            $this->path_short = array_pop($this->path); // filename
            $this->path_short = end($this->path) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this->path_short; // dir+file
        }
    } // fn shortenPath

} // cl MyErrorExceptionHandler
```

The title of this question is probably a little bit off because I'm not 100% on the terminology. Basically I'm trying to figure out a few things.

1. Is it right to explicitly declare `$level` and `$path` as arrays?
2. Should `$level` be declared as it is (and made `$this->level`)? If so, have I assigned its value (`E_WARNING` etc.) in a wise place? Would the constructor (not shown here) be a smarter choice?
3. Note the commented block in `myErrorHandler()`. Originally I had declared all of these properties at the top of the class, and then called `$this->printMessage()` without any parameters. Which is the more correct way? If I keep the code as is, would I want to then use `$this->severity = $severity` etc. inside `printMessage()`?
4. So, would it be better to:

replace

```
$this->shortenPath($file);
echo ' in ' . $this->path_short . ' on line ' . $line;
```

with

```
$path_short = $this->shortenPath($file);
echo ' in ' . $path_short . ' on line ' . $line;
```

ultimately, and give a return value in `shortenPath()`?

I realize this is a mishmash of several different questions, but what I'm trying to get at is a common inquiry about the proper style of declaring/using variables/properties, specifically when dealing with methods.

To summarize: **When should I use `$this->foo = $foo`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: sorry, I have assumed below that you would create a new instance of the 'object' with each error which obviously you are not doing. Just edited my answer to reflect this.

"When should I use $this->foo = $foo?"

There can be several cases in which you would do this, but it's usually if you create $foo within a method and wish to have that then accessed by the entire object.

For example, if you wanted to call on an object and use that within this particular object (if it doesn't make sense to extend). You would do something like:

```
$foo = new DataModel();
$this->foo = $foo;
```

OR

```
$this->foo = new DataModel();
```

That object may be a decorator or something else related to error handling and the above code would usually feature in your constructor. You could then access the methods of that object any time by using:

```
$this->foo->objectMethod();
```

..and to express something noted in the comments to this answer:

> "would you assign $file to the object as that is used in several methods?"
>
> I wouldn't assign $file to the object,
>   here's why. The semantics of the word
>   "property" means "belongs to". In your
>   case, your class is a error handler.
>   $file doesn't belong to the error
>   handler, it belongs to an error
>   instance. If your class was
>   MyErrorHandler_Error (created for each
>   instance of a triggered error), then
>   $file would be a property of that
>   class, along with $line and $level.

To answer what I can from your other questions:

1. It's neither. I would consider it preference.
2. Yes - any variables or values which should be available to your entire object and required for the object to run properly, should probably be set within your constructor, if not within your variable declarations (not sure of terminology there) at the top of the class.
3. read the comments below. Because this particular class deals with multiple instances of errors - assigning the properties of those errors to the object wouldn't be best practice as you will be overwriting them with each new error. However, it does make sense to store all of your errors and error properties within an array assigned to the object if you require to access historical data. For example, at the moment, if you create a new error - that is all you are doing. You have no way of accessing any old errors this object has created.
4. see above

You should also think about conflicts when assigning properties to objects. Are you likely to reassign, because if so, the old property will be gone. Fairly simple but still something you have to consider.

Comment: Thanks! I am wondering about this, though: "If you will need any property in more than one method, then it is advised you assign that property to your object. If printMessage() is the only method which uses those properties, then no." Take, for example, $file. It goes from myErrorHandler(), to printMessage(), to shortenPath(). These could all be in one method, but I broke them up for readability/practicality. So yes, that's more than one method, but $file will only ever travel that chain. There's a whole long method for Exceptions which I did not include here, and which never touches $file.

Comment: I wouldn't assign `$file` to the object, here's why. The semantics of the word "property" means "belongs to". In your case, your class is a error handler. `$file` doesn't belong to the error handler, it belongs to an error instance. If your class was `MyErrorHandler_Error` (created for each instance of a triggered error), then `$file` would be a property of that class, along with `$line` and `$level`.

Comment: Actually this line appears in the constructor: set_error_handler(array($this, 'myErrorHandler'));. That is, myErrorHandler() is only ever called by PHP itself when an error is triggered. So no, no part of this class will ever be manually accessed. Maybe I should've started my adventures in OO PHP somewhere a bit simpler. :P So I agree with you: If these methods/properties were being accessed outside the class/manually, I'd just $this->foo = $foo everything. But since that will never happen, I thought maybe I should stick with just $foo/$file/whatever unless best practice dictates otherwise.

Comment: @netcoder: Exactly what I was trying to get at in the above (late) comment. Thanks!

Comment: @netcoder - fully agree. If I'd looked at the expected implementation of this class would have seen that :S

Comment: @Zenph: Sorry for not pointing that out in the question. I should've left the constructor in for clarity.

Comment: @CartoonChess - no problem. Just updated my answer to reflect that. I should have known anyway - your other methods are private and your class is clearly called errorhandler with a method for creating new errors.